# How to launch an ECR image on EKS cluster using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, amazon-ecr

As in the title, I have uploaded an image to ECR and I would like to deploy this to EKS, is this possible using Terraform?

I have already done the following with Terraform

- Launched running EKS Cluster
- Pushed my image to ECR

But I cannot seem to find an example of changing EKS to use the ECR image.

Comment: What is stopping you from providing the image location in the deployment template?